# Cannot access Windows 7 shared drive from OS X

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, shared-folders

I have a shared drive I: in Windows 7, I want to access that drive from my Mac, but I am not able to connect to my windows. From *Finder > Go > Connect to server*

```
smb://192.168.0.101
```

It asks me for a Name and Password, I am entering name/passowrd that I used for my Windows account, but nothing happens after I click connect.

I can access internet on both my Windows 7 PC and Mac. I can ping from PC to mac and mac to PC
What settings I need to get to that folder in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link would fix the problem?

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/556-windows-7-file-sharing-with-mac-os-x/

These links might also help:
http://www.trickyways.com/2010/06/how-to-access-mac-files-from-windows-7/
http://www.trickyways.com/2011/08/access-pc-windows-7-files-from-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: He already performed those steps. And second link makes no sense since he wants windows folder in mac not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to look into is the security level Windows 7 is using.  On the Windows 7 machine:

1. Go to *Administrative Tools*.
2. Go to *Local Security Policy*.
3. Double click *Local Policies*.
4. Double click *Security Options*.
5. Find *Network security:  LAN Manager authentication level*.

By default Windows 7 is set to *Send NTLMv2 response only*.  This is Microsoft attempting to make Windows 7 more secure; however, it has the added effect of blocking requests from older operating systems that do not understand NTLMv2.  I had a similar problem mapping a drive in Windows 7 to a file share on an AS400.  I would receive the pop-up for my user name and password.  Enter both correctly, then be prompted for credentials again.  It would never go through.

Change the policy to *Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated*.  It will use NTLMv2 if it can but use a less secure authentication level if needed.

Answer (score 2):

just want to make a note here that the smb protocol actually checks for the date of the authentication request.  i had a similar problem and it turned out to be that i had accidentally changed the date on my windows pc in the bios and so it would not accept my credentials no matter what.  setting the date correctly fixed it for me.

that's kind of a special case, but i figure worth mentioning as an easy thing to overlook.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put WORKGROUP\username in the username field ?

It will be helpful if you can see samba logs on windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

go to **network and sharing center**
click **advanced network and sharing settings**
scroll down...
under password protected sharing **turn off password protected sharing**
it worked for me....

Comment: I'd argue against removing password protection, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set user rights for *sharepath* not only in Network and Sharing Settings but in properties of the folder in security settings. I added `guest` as I've tried doing in the advanced sharing menu and *Voila!* I can now connect to *share* as `guest` without any problems from OS X. (Also, if you want to use Share Read / Writable, just set Full Access for the guest account.)